# How do I vertically align my text in a table header to the bottom?

Tags: css, html-table

I have a series of tables that lays on a top table and this is the basic structure:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
            <thead>
         <table>
         <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
              </tr>
            <thead>
         <table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want all tables to be the same height so all tables have a width property. But when the data fills the tables th sometimes the title contain two words and I want to break it:
"TITLE
TITLE"
But once I do it, the other 1-word titles are getting bottom padding and it looks far from the bottom of the th cell
[image]

Is there any way to make all 1-word titles closer to the bottom of the cell?

Comment: Why are you using several tables? This looks like it should be done using just the one table. You can align text using `vertical-align: bottom;` on the `th`’s.

Comment: The multiple tables related to design requirements. But thank you for the answer, it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be solved with the CSS property vertical-align set to bottom.

Like this:

```css
.align-bottom {
   vertical-align: bottom
}
```

```html
<th class="align-bottom"></th>
```